# How to access SAP backend tables using SAPUI5?

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, sapui5, abap

I'm totally new to SAPUI5 and after learning the classic Dynpro and developing on the SAP GUI I got a few questions about how SAPUI5 works.

As SAPUI5 is developed in Eclipse I'm interested how it could get data from a SAP NetWeaver table.

Do I need a remote call for that? And how does the Eclipse program connect and communicate with NetWeaver?

I didn't find an answer to that, maybe it's just too simple.

Maybe someone have some tips or best practice to share?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAPUI5 apps are running inside the user's browser and connect to any server with HTTP. This is actually the very standard way of creating client-side web applications. You can use any kind of HTTP server as long as they offer the data at a URL and offer the data in a well-known format like JSON or XML, but when you have a Netweaver server, Gateway and using OData would be the recommended way to go.

Don't think too much about Eclipse. It is not at all required to develop SAPUI5 applications, it just used to be a well-supported editor with additional plugins in the past. Actually SAP WebIDE would be the best-integrated editor now, but you can still use anything from vim to Notepad.

There are plenty of Gateway/SAPUI5 guides on the web, also the official UI5 documentation contains [chapters](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/44062441f3bd4c67a4f665ae362d1109.html) about getting data from the server with OData. I'd recommend doing the entire walkthrough to any beginner!

Comment: Thank you akudev! That was a very useful answer :) Perfectly explained (for a beginner) how it works and what I can do. I will do the walkthrough now. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a service (as far as I know preferably using SAP NetWeaver Gateway) to expose whatever data and operations you wish to access from the back-end system.